# .NET Core - Able to connect to Azure App Config but can't return any config values?

Tags: c#, azure, .net-core, azure-functions

I have a .NET Core Azure Function app where I am connecting to an Azure App Config service and registering a Key Vault connection:

```
using Azure.Identity;
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using System;

[assembly: FunctionsStartup(typeof(Func.Accounts.Api.Startup))]

namespace Func.Accounts.Api
{
    public class Startup : FunctionsStartup
    {
        public override void ConfigureAppConfiguration(IFunctionsConfigurationBuilder builder)
        {
            string connectionString = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("AppConfigConnectionString");

            builder.ConfigurationBuilder.AddAzureAppConfiguration(options =>
            {
                options.Connect(connectionString)
                    .ConfigureKeyVault(kv =>
                    {
                        kv.SetCredential(new DefaultAzureCredential());
                    });
            });
        }

        public override void Configure(IFunctionsHostBuilder builder)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

I can connect to the service fine, and I can see through the Azure portal that it is receiving requests however I cannot get it to actually return any config values. This is what the config looks like after its been injected into the function:

[image]

I know there are 3 config values in the App Config Service but it does not return any data and I cannot see where it is failing. As far as I can tell there isn't an authentication issue and I have achieved this successfully in a different project using the same method.

Interestingly, if I try to retrieve the key through the `Azure App Configuration client library` I get the following `404` error on the `GetConfigurationSetting` method. I'm struggling to understand how it doesn't see any of my config settings.

[image]

Comment: While debugging is `connectionString` actually being populated correctly from environment variables?

Comment: @Nkosi it is yes. When that's been the issue in the past, an authentication error is thrown. And as I said, I can see the requests coming in in the Azure portal and the AppConfigurationEndpoint shown in the screenshot about is the correct URI taken from the connection string.

Comment: post your code please.

Comment: A couple of things to look at: Can Azure App Config access Key Vault (you need to configure this)? Does your config values have any labels?

Comment: @lopezbertoni From the documentation I was under the impression that Azure App Config dosen't/can't access key vault directly and its the consuming application that needs to authenticate against it. In terms of the labels - yes they do have label, does that effect how you call the service?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the comments, it looks like you need to do two things:

1. If you're using labels, you need to add a filter for them when you configure your application.
2. If you're using Azure Key Vault, make sure that you [grant access to your App Configuration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-app-configuration/use-key-vault-references-dotnet-core?tabs=core5x#grant-your-app-access-to-key-vault)

Here's an example of loading the configuration using labels.

```
[assembly: FunctionsStartup(typeof(Host.Example.Startup))]

namespace Host.Example
{
    public partial class Startup : FunctionsStartup
    {
        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; set;  }

        public override void ConfigureAppConfiguration(IFunctionsConfigurationBuilder builder)
        {
            var config = builder.ConfigurationBuilder.Build();

            var appConfigConnection = config.GetConnectionString("AppConfig");
            // Here the label is the environment name
            var environment = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("Environment");

            builder.ConfigurationBuilder.AddAzureAppConfiguration(options =>
            {
                // Load the configuration using labels
                // Connect it to the Key Vault. Didn't test the Key Vault code but it should work if configured properly
                options.Connect(appConfigConnection)
                    .Select(KeyFilter.Any, environment.ToLowerInvariant())
                    .ConfigureKeyVault(kv =>
                    {
                        kv.SetCredential(new DefaultAzureCredential());
                    });
            });
        }

        public override void Configure(IFunctionsHostBuilder builder)
        {
            Configuration = builder.GetContext().Configuration;
        }
    }
}
```